# Redirect DOCROOT to specific application - Apache fronting Tomcat

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an `Apache` fronting a Tomcat application. I want to change the document root of the application to a specific Tomcat application. What I want to do is this:

- If the website name is example.com, typing www.example.com or example.com or any such variant should lead you to example.com/ebb **without** any change in URL.

I have tried:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/eb/$1 [P]
```

This did not work. I keep getting redirected to the Apache test page.

Where am I going wrong? How do I get this right?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat runs on port 8080 by default and what you're trying to run is a website on port 8080 by providing only the url

```
"www.example.com" will go to port 80 and not port 8080 by default.
```

Specify what is the final solution you want to achieve.

Also I could see you've written you have an apache fronting a tomcat application. Well in that case, if this what I'm thinking it is. All you need to do now is to put up a new host in apache virtual host config file with proxypass and proxypassreverse paramteres.